# Pass array to .Find function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have this macro and I'm desperate to pass the array to the .Find function (the array's been set to hold values from a column). The code constantly drops an error message, and I just cannot figure out the reason.
I need to look up those values stored in the array in a worksheet and examine those rows they appear in. With that part I have no problem what so ever. What I don't seem to get is that if I pass the array with a given index (strArray(5)) its all fine, yet when i am trying to generalize the process and grab all values needed the error message pops up.... I assume I screwed up the loops... I cant get them right

[image]

```
Sub test()


Dim fnd As String, FirstFound As String
Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range
Dim total As Integer
Dim mysum As Integer
Dim myavg As Integer
Dim mymedi As Integer
Dim mystdev As Integer
Dim mycrows As Integer
Dim mydistro As Integer
Dim strArray() As String
Dim TotalRows As Long
Dim i As Integer

    TotalRows = Sheets("Template").Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim strArray(4 To TotalRows)

    For i = 4 To TotalRows
        strArray(i) = Sheets("Template").Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next

    MsgBox "Loaded " & UBound(strArray) & " items!"
    MsgBox strArray(5)

'search tag

For i = 4 To 135
fnd = strArray(i)
Next

Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=fnd, after:=LastCell)

'Test to see if anything was found
  If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
  Else
    GoTo NothingFound
  End If

Set rng = FoundCell

'Loop until cycled through all unique finds
  Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
    'Find next cell with fnd value
      Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)

    'Add found cell to rng range variable
      Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)

    'Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
      If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do
  Loop

For i = 4 To 135
'sum test for signedamount
    total = rng.EntireRow.Columns("N")
    mysum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(total)
    Sheets("Template").Columns("A").Find(strArray(i)).Rows.Columns("B").Value = mysum
'avg test for signedamount
    total = rng.EntireRow.Columns("N")
    myavg = WorksheetFunction.Average(total)
    Sheets("Template").Columns("A").Find(strArray(i)).Rows.Columns("C").Value = myavg
'medi test for signedamount
    total = rng.EntireRow.Columns("N")
    mymedi = WorksheetFunction.Median(total)
    Sheets("Template").Columns("A").Find(strArray(i)).Rows.Columns("E").Value = mymedi
'stdev test for signedamount
    total = rng.EntireRow.Columns("N")
    mystdev = WorksheetFunction.StDev(total)
    Sheets("Template").Columns("A").Find(strArray(i)).Rows.Columns("F").Value = mystdev
'crows
    mycrows = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H1000"), strArray(i))
    Sheets("Template").Columns("A").Find(strArray(i)).Rows.Columns("V").Value = mycrows

'sum test for amount1
    total = rng.EntireRow.Columns("O")
    mysum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(total)
    Sheets("Template").Columns("A").Find(strArray(i)).Rows.Columns("L").Value = mysum
'avg test for amount1
    total = rng.EntireRow.Columns("O")
    myavg = WorksheetFunction.Average(total)
    Sheets("Template").Columns("A").Find(strArray(i)).Rows.Columns("M").Value = myavg
'medi test for amount1
    total = rng.EntireRow.Columns("O")
    mymedi = WorksheetFunction.Median(total)
    Sheets("Template").Columns("A").Find(strArray(i)).Rows.Columns("O").Value = mymedi
'stdev test for amount1
    total = rng.EntireRow.Columns("O")
    mystdev = WorksheetFunction.StDev(total)
    Sheets("Template").Columns("A").Find(strArray(i)).Rows.Columns("P").Value = mystdev
'distro
Next

Exit Sub

'Error Handler
NothingFound:
      MsgBox "No values were found in this worksheet"

    End Sub
```

Comment: Please specify the line of code that returns the error

Comment: If `TotalRows` is not `135` you must be getting an error.

Comment: yeah.. felt like i missed somethiing    `Sheets("Template").Columns("A").Find(strArray(i)).Rows.Columns("B").Value = mysum`

Comment: This code executed without errors for me against some boring sample data. You will also need to provide your data in order to reproduce the error

Comment: @TheTTGGuy - in your "boring sample data", what is the value of `total` after this line - `total = rng.EntireRow.Columns("N")`. Just curious.

Comment: Sorry, let me be more clear. I did get an error. The total calculates 0 which caused the stdev to produce an error, but it's a different error than OP. I got "unable to get the stdev property of the worksheet class"

Comment: I need to set up this macro to monitor transactions. First i pull in cardholderIDs from a sheet that we download daily. In that report we got a log of transactions and sure enough one ID might be recurring as the report logs all activities related to an ID. I have a Template sheet into which this macro needs to sort the cardholderIDs and calculate some info (avg, median, deviation, etc). respectively. Just to make it a bit less foggy.